# Why won't my compiler vectorize a loop with Bessel functions (but will for e.g. exponential functions)?

Tags: c, vectorization

I am trying to get my compiler (Microsoft compiler on Windows) to vectorize a loop that contains (among other things) Bessel functions from math.h. A simple example is:

```
double vec[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    vec[i] = j0(i);
}
```

Compiled with `cl /O2 /fp:fast /Qvec-report:2` produces the message:

`info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'`.

Where the `1200` code refers to:

> Loop contains loop-carried data dependencies that prevent vectorization. Different iterations of the loop interfere with each other such that vectorizing the loop would produce wrong answers, and the auto-vectorizer can't prove to itself that there aren't such data dependencies.

On the other hand, the exponential function works as intended:

```
double vec[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    vec[i] = exp(i);
}
```

Compiled with `cl /O2 /fp:fast /Qvec-report:2` produces the message:

`info C5001: loop vectorized`.

Does anyone know why the first loop does not get vectorized?

Comment: This is just my guess, but maybe because there are [SIMD instructions to compute `exp`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=exponential&ig_expand=2959) while there are no SIMD instructions to compute Bessel functions?

Comment: In general, function calls cannot be vectorized, so a better question would be how the compiler *can* vectorize the second loop.  Presumably, the compiler has special handling for `exp()` that includes the ability to vectorize calls to it.  Or perhaps it is simply able to inline `exp()`, which could be enough.

Comment: @MikeCAT your guess is correct

Comment: In general, functions that can get inlined can get vectorized because then the compiler can determine that calling the function doesn't come with side effects.